# Read from STDIN on a Git pre-commit Hook (with PHP)

Tags: php, git, stdin, hook

I'm looking for a way to have `git-commit` wait for standard input. I'm coding this in `PHP`, as my `bash` skills are non-existant, so I thougth doing a regular

```
<?php
$input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $line);
?>
```

would do the trick, and wait until I write stuff in to continue, but it just goes ahead and continues executing my PHP script anyways.

The idea behind this is that after I tag a release, git will push `HEAD` to the testing webserver, send a couple of tweets, and let me write in some details about the release in the CHANGELOG.

While I can achieve the writing to a file (using `exec('mate -w')`), I'd like it to hang on until I do a quick test on the server. This would enable me to rollback if I notice any errors (lazy, I know).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try using `exec < /dev/tty` as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/67834

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most git hooks either have something special fed to there stdin, or have stdin detached from the terminal. They are all designed to be run non-interactively, so I don't believe that a hook is suitable for what you want to do. You can, of course, manually talk to `/dev/tty` but I don't think that it's a very good idea.

I also don't believe that the 'pre-commit' hook is suitable to your task, surely not every commit that you make will be a release of some sort? A 'post-receive' hook on the testing webserver machine sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, actually I found I'd be better off keeping some variables on the .git/config file for these purposes, and having the server do these related tasks.

It was more a problem of my idea of a workflow than git itself, it turns out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I need user input in my post-merge hook (written in PHP).

I solved it with this piece of code: `trim(exec('exec < /dev/tty && read input && echo $input'))`

Don't ask, it works ;)

Comment: never "Dont ask". Especially with user input and commandline

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) does extend the run-hooks API to allow feeding data from the standard input when running the hook script(s).

That can facilitate reading from STDIN on a Git pre-commit Hook, something which is not natively supported, and start being implemented with Git 2.40 (but only for [`git hook run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5/Documentation/git-hook.txt#L22), not yet any all hook automatic execution).

See [commit 0414b38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5), [commit 96af564](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96af564d2781e76139474051c7651136d5c74652), [commit 917e080](https://github.com/git/git/commit/917e0802493a39d77c4bdbdf9aaa5d8d69b7a7b0), [commit 5402673](https://github.com/git/git/commit/540267304d37d6257edb3144e770693071d8fbb7) (08 Feb 2023) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
See [commit 5123e6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5123e6e7bd3b0bf3777cb77e36d141f76d8604a4) (08 Feb 2023) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5048df6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5048df67b295baeaaa6dafb16ff712bd2a62731a), 22 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`hook`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5): support a `--to-stdin=<path>` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Expose the `"path_to_stdin"` API added in the preceding commit in the "[`git hook run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5/Documentation/git-hook.txt#L22)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hook#Documentation/git-hook.txt-run))</sup> command.
>
> For now we won't be using this command interface outside of the tests, but exposing this functionality makes it easier to test the hook API.
> The plan is to use this to extend the "`sendemail-validate`" hook ([thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/ad152e25-4061-9955-d3e6-a2c8b1bd24e7@amd.com/), [thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20230120012459.920932-1-michael.strawbridge@amd.com)).

`git hook` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5/Documentation/git-hook.txt#L11):

> '`git hook`' run `[--ignore-missing] [--to-stdin=<path>] <hook-name> [-- <hook-args>]`

`git hook` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0414b3891cd3adb80b879c7be49d9b727e2b23f5/Documentation/git-hook.txt#L34-L38):

> ### `--to-stdin`
>
> For "`run`"; Specify a file which will be streamed into the
> hook's stdin. The hook will receive the entire file from
> beginning to EOF.