# How do I prompt the user from within a commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, hook, commit-message

I want to warn the user if their commit message doesn't follow a certain set of guidelines, and then give them the option to edit their commit message, ignore the warning, or cancel the commit. The problem is that I don't seem to have access to `stdin`.

Below is my commit-msg file:

```sh
function verify_info {
    if [ -z "$(grep '$2:.*[a-zA-Z]' $1)" ]
    then
        echo >&2 $2 information should not be omitted
        local_editor=`git config --get core.editor`
        if [ -z "${local_editor}" ]
        then
            local_editor=${EDITOR}
        fi
        echo "Do you want to"
        select CHOICE in "edit the commit message" "ignore this warning" "cancel the commit"; do
            case ${CHOICE} in
                i*) echo "Warning ignored"
                    ;;
                e*) ${local_editor} $1
                    verify_info "$1" $2
                    ;;
                *)  echo "CHOICE = ${CHOICE}"
                    exit 1
                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
}

verify_info "$1" "Scope"
if [ $# -ne 0 ];
then
    exit $#
fi
verify_info "$1" "Affects"
if [ $# -ne 0 ];
then
    exit $#
fi

exit 0
```

Here is the output when I leave the Scope information blank:

```
Scope information should not be omitted
Do you want to:
1) edit the commit message  3) cancel the commit
2) ignore this warning
#?
```

The message is correct, but it doesn't actually stop for input. I've also tried using the simpler `read` command, and it has the same problem. It seems that the problem is that at this point git has control of `stdin` and is providing its own input. How do I fix this?

Update: It seems this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067874/read-from-stdin-on-a-git-pre-commit-hook-with-php) which unfortunately seems to suggest I'm out of luck.

Comment: When you have access to a X Server you can escape to a graphical dialog tool. Ugly-but-works

Comment: Instead of the error message you could simply provide an informative error message -- including echoing the necessary command to ignore the warning.

Comment: @btspierre, that's the approach I ended up taking. At the advice of John Feminella, I allowed the use of a environment variable to override the warning, and just echo the warning whenever a bad situation is encountered.

Comment: @Rudi: I'm not sure what you'd escape to the X Server, as git seems to have complete control of stdin.

Comment: I mean when you have a graphical user interface running you can "escape" from the terminal by running a graphical dialog box(like xdialog or kdialog), which is not bound to any tty. See http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Shell_Scripting_with_KDE_Dialogs or  or http://xdialog.free.fr/ for further details.

Comment: 10 years later,  this is being discussed: https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.790.git.1605625363309.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#u

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Calling `exec < /dev/tty` assigns standard input to the keyboard. Works for me in a post-commit git hook:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "[post-commit hook] Commit done!"

# Allows us to read user input below, assigns stdin to keyboard
exec < /dev/tty

while true; do
  read -p "[post-commit hook] Check for outdated gems? (Y/n) " yn
  if [ "$yn" = "" ]; then
    yn='Y'
  fi
  case $yn in
      [Yy] ) bundle outdated --pre; break;;
      [Nn] ) exit;;
      * ) echo "Please answer y or n for yes or no.";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: STDIN can be closed again with `exec <&-`

Comment: If you're using Ruby, that'd translate to `STDIN.reopen('/dev/tty')`. Awesome stuff, this is the real answer.

Comment: This is awesome, but it may break when committing from another tool, such as an editor. Not sure how to get around that, but if someone has an idea, I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: This even works in `bash` under [MingW32](http://www.mingw.org/) (GNU-ish Windows layer). Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Python, that'd translate to `sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty", "r")`. Might help someone :)

Comment: If I dont assign this, where does my standard input go??

Comment: What can you do if you're on Windows? I am asking because in Windows you don't have the "/dev/tty" file. (asking more precisely for python, but any response I could understand and translate it into python)

Answer (score 6):

The `commit-msg` hook is not run in an interactive environment (as you have noticed).

The only way to reliable notify the user would be to write an error to stdout, place a copy of the commit message in a `BAD_MSG` file and instruct the user to edit the file and `git commit --file=BAD_MSG`

---

If you have some control over the environment you could have an alternate editor which is a wrapper script that checks the proposed message, and can restart the editor with an extra commented message.

Basically, you run the editor, check the file saved against your rules. and if it fails, prepend your warning message (with leading `#`) to the file and restart the editor.

You could even allow them to put in a `#FORCE=true` line in the message which would suppress the check and continue.

Comment: Try calling `exec < /dev/tty` first in the script to be able to capture user input - see other answer.

Comment: Although this is a well thought out answer, Eliot's should be accepted as he proves it *is* actually possible!

Comment: The user can skip hooks with `--no-verify`, do need to resort on `#FORCE=true` hackery.

Comment: @MattFletcher It's possible in a terminal. If you are using a graphical frontend then it might stop being possible as you'll get errors about it not understanding what `/dev/tty` is.

Answer (score 6):

```sh
read -p "Question? [y|n] " -n 1 -r < /dev/tty
echo
if echo $REPLY | grep -E '^[Yy]$' > /dev/null; then
#do if Yes
else
#do if No
fi
```

Comment: thanks. I love this answer. For zsh just do `read "?Question? [y|n]" < /dev/tty` no extra option needed

Comment: This also worked for allowing running `docker exec -it` (which changes the output formatting for php-doc-check)

Answer (score 2):

this works fine when running git commit from command line. On windows (haven't tryed on linux) if you use gitk or git-gui you won't be able to prompt because you get an error on the `exec < /dev/tty` line.

The sollution is to call `git-bash.exe` in your hook:

`.git/hooks/post-commit` contains:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /c/Program\ Files/Git/git-bash.exe /path/to/my_repo/.git/hooks/post-checkout.sh
```

the `.git/hooks/post-commit.sh` file contains:

```sh
# --------------------------------------------------------
# usage: f_askContinue "my question ?"
function f_askContinue {
  local myQuestion=$1

  while true; do
     read -p "${myQuestion} " -n 1 -r answer
     case $answer in
        [Yy]* ) printf "\nOK\n"; break;;
        [Nn]* )   printf "\nAbandon\n";
                  exit;;
        * ) printf "\nAnswer with Yes or No.\n";;
     esac
  done
}

f_askContinue "Do you want to continue ?"
echo "This command is executed after the prompt !"
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to do it in Node.js or TypeScript**

**EDIT:** I made an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/force-stdin-tty)

---

I see people commenting on how to do it for other languages in [Eliot Sykes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/7381355), but the JavaScript solution is a bit long so I'll make a separate answer.

I'm not sure if [`O_NOCTTY`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_open_constants) is required, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. I don't really understand what a controlling terminal is. [GNU docs description](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open_002dtime-Flags.html#index-O_005fNOCTTY). I think what it means is that with `O_NOCTTY` on, you wouldn't be able to send a `CTRL+C` to the process (if it doesn't already have a controlling terminal). In that case, I'll leave it on so you don't control spawned processes. The main node process should already have a controlling terminal, I think.

I adapted the answer from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/365#issuecomment-260574249)

I don't see any docs on how to use the `tty.ReadStream` constructor so I did a bit of trial and error / digging through [Node.js source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.7.0/lib/tty.js#L42-L64).

You have to use `Object.defineProperty` because [Node.js internals](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6271ef005eb311c819b7ab041e09f50e4155ec1e/lib/internal/bootstrap/node.js#L354-L358) uses it too, and doesn't define a setter. An alternative is to do `process.stdin.fd = fd`, but I get duplicate output that way.

Anyway, I wanted to use this with [Husky.js](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and it seems to work so far. I should probably turn this into an npm package when I get the time.

Node.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs');
const tty = require('tty');

if (!process.stdin.isTTY) {
  const { O_RDONLY, O_NOCTTY } = fs.constants;
  let fd;
  try {
    fd = fs.openSync('/dev/tty', O_RDONLY + O_NOCTTY);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Please push your code in a terminal.');
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const stdin = new tty.ReadStream(fd);

  Object.defineProperty(process, 'stdin', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => stdin,
  });
}

...Do your stuff...

process.stdin.destroy();
process.exit(0);
```

TypeScript:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

import fs from 'fs';
import tty from 'tty';

if (!process.stdin.isTTY) {
  const { O_RDONLY, O_NOCTTY } = fs.constants;
  let fd;
  try {
    fd = fs.openSync('/dev/tty', O_RDONLY + O_NOCTTY);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Please push your code in a terminal.');
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // @ts-ignore: `ReadStream` in @types/node incorrectly expects an object.
  // https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/37174
  const stdin = new tty.ReadStream(fd);

  Object.defineProperty(process, 'stdin', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => stdin,
  });
}

...Do your stuff...

process.stdin.destroy();
process.exit(0);
```

Comment: Hi 
Am a noob in node and git , am planning to write hooks in node js, i have a scenrio where i need to capture user input to run eslint or not,no matter what i do the hook execution happens without a pause for user input , then i read that we have to attach dev/tty 
i was googling a lot on how to do that , came across your repo, i thought maybe you would have some idea on the same, if this is not the right place to contact, my apologies in advance

can you please let me know how to capture user input in git hooks written in node?
will your package help me here?

Comment: I think you are the same person that posted on my [repo](https://github.com/dosentmatter/force-stdin-tty/issues/2). I think you are on windows and `/dev/tty` doesn't exist on windows. You can try using the `CON` device.

Comment: Sadly Windows does not have an exact equivalent to /dev/tty, and attempting to open 'con' using fs.openSync with the specified flags (O_RDONLY + O_NOCTTY) is not a valid approach on Windows systems. You found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

To make `select` stop for input, you may also try to redirect the `stdin` of `select` from `/dev/fd/3` (See: [Read input in bash inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop)).

```
# sample code using a while loop to simulate git consuming stdin
{ 
echo 'fd 0' | while read -r stdin; do
   echo "stdin: $stdin"
   echo "Do you want to"
   select CHOICE in "edit the commit message" "ignore this warning" "cancel the commit"; do
      case ${CHOICE} in
         i*) echo "Warning ignored"
             ;;
         e*) echo ${local_editor} $1
             echo verify_info "$1" $2
             ;;
         *)  echo "CHOICE = ${CHOICE}"
             exit 1
             ;;
      esac
   done 0<&3 3<&-
done
} 3<&- 3<&0
```