# Read user input inside a loop

Tags: bash

I am having a bash script which is something like following,

```
cat filename | while read line
do
    read input;
    echo $input;
done
```

but this is clearly not giving me the right output as when I do read in the while loop it tries to read from the file filename because of the possible I/O redirection.

Any other way of doing the same?

Comment: Same thing happens  when you switch user in bash and run read command under switched user in script

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Read from the controlling terminal device:

```
read input </dev/tty
```

more info: http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/Fixing-stdin-inside-a-redirected-loop

Comment: -1, as this will circumvent any other redirect. For example, `bash yourscript < /foo/bar` will wait for user input, this is acceptable only when reading passwords. The answer by @GordonDavisson is preferable for all other uses.

Answer (score 70):

You can redirect the regular stdin through unit 3 to keep the get it inside the pipeline:

```
{ cat notify-finished | while read line; do
    read -u 3 input
    echo "$input"
done; } 3<&0
```

BTW, if you really are using `cat` this way, replace it with a redirect and things become even easier:

```
while read line; do
    read -u 3 input
    echo "$input"
done 3<&0 <notify-finished
```

Or, you can swap stdin and unit 3 in that version -- read the file with unit 3, and just leave stdin alone:

```
while read line <&3; do
    # read & use stdin normally inside the loop
    read input
    echo "$input"
done 3<notify-finished
```

Comment: why is your second script hanging?

Comment: @LucaBorrione: How are you using it? Is it waiting for you to give it input (note that `read line` is reading from notify-finished, but if you just run it as written `read -u 3 input` is reading from the console)?

Comment: I get `read: 3: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor` when tryiing to do `read -u 3`

Comment: @maxprehl I assume you're using the first version? Did you include the `3<&0` part in the redirect after `done` (but before the redirect from the input file)? That's what sets up file descriptor 3.

Comment: example 3 is perfect. removing `cat input_file | while` also has the benefit, that inside the `while` loop, you can modify variables of the parent scope. see also [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered). the `cat input_file` could be moved to a process substitution like `done 3< <(cat input_file)`

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the loop like this:

```
for line in $(cat filename); do
    read input
    echo $input;
done
```

Unit test:

```
for line in $(cat /etc/passwd); do
    read input
    echo $input;
    echo "[$line]"
done
```

Comment: @w2lame Tested again, change "while" loop to "for" loop - working for me. Try "sex -x" see where is error comes from

Comment: don't use cat, see answer from Hai Vu

Comment: +1. This was much easier to implement for my specific needs than other suggestions.

Comment: See [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) on the Wooledge wiki. Also, http://shellcheck.net/ warning [SC2013](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2013)

Answer (score 3):

I have found this parameter -u with read.

"-u 1" means "read from stdout"

```
while read -r newline; do
    ((i++))
    read -u 1 -p "Doing $i""th file, called $newline. Write your answer and press Enter!"
    echo "Processing $newline with $REPLY" # united input from two different read commands.
done <<< $(ls)
```

Comment: This is not stdin. FD 1 which is not flushed and you can read from it. You also can use `read -u 2`.

Comment: Well, if it is not an stdin, why can I not to use FD 12??? (I am not an expert. I only wonder.)

Comment: I was also wondering. but it seems because the FD 12 does not exist. FD 0 is the stdin.
FD 1 stdout FD 2 error. it also works with the error descriptor as I wrote above. 
`read -u 2`

Comment: Yes. The file with FD=12 is not open yet. I corrected the text. Thanks for the hit. :-)

Answer (score -7):

```
echo "Enter the Programs you want to run:"
> ${PROGRAM_LIST}
while read PROGRAM_ENTRY
do
   if [ ! -s ${PROGRAM_ENTRY} ]
   then
      echo ${PROGRAM_ENTRY} >> ${PROGRAM_LIST}
   else
      break
   fi
done
```