# How to copy stdin into two files?

Tags: bash, unix, io

I need to have `script.sh`, that would create files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` with content that was sent to stdin. For example:

```
echo ABRACODABRA | script.sh
```

...should create files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` with the content `ABRACODABRA`.

How can I do this?

Please provide `script.sh`'s body!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `tee`.

```
$ echo 'foo' | tee f1.txt f2.txt
```

or

```
$ echo 'foo' | tee f1.txt > f2.txt
```

to suppress the additional output to stdout.

I'm guessing your real problem could be how to read from input inside a script. In this case, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop). That will give you something like

```
while read input; do
    echo $input | tee -a f1.txt > f2.txt
done
```

Comment: And how can I do it _inside_ script.sh?

Comment: The same way you would outside.

Comment: What should i write inside script.sh?

Comment: I would ditch the while loop entirely and just run `tee  f1.text > f2.txt` (or similar). I can't see any advantage to having the shell read STDIN before passing it to `tee`.

Comment: @Patrick that's what bos says above :) for some reason it didn't satisfy the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your script can look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 read msg
 echo $msg > f1.txt
 echo $msg > f2.txt
 exit 0
```