# bash file reading by line; simultaneously allow interactive stdin?

Tags: bash

I think I'm pushing the limits of bash here but I really want to get this done without having to re-write the entire script.

I have something dynamic that is a list of pairs of files which I want to perform operations on. I also want to prompt before I continue with any of the tasks.

It looks like this:

```
diff -rq $dir1 $dir2 | \
    sed -ne 's/^Files \(.*\) and \(.*\) differ$/\1 \2/p' | \
    while read differingfilepair; do
        ...
        printf "Continue? (Y/n)"
        read -n1 cont
    done
```

As you can see here the `while read line` block appears to function as some form of a subshell which receives the content of the data over STDIN.

The `$cont` variable basically just slurps the first char of each line of that data (the first char in the path of the first file in the pair of files reported by `diff` to be differing), it's not attached to the terminal.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here? I guess a workaround is to use a temporary file but is there another way?

**Edit:** Using a temporary file later loaded into the `while read` block like this: `while read l; do ...; done < .tmp_file` still takes over stdin! (though I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771857/340947) will help)

Comment: Yes that seems to be part of the equation for a file descriptor redirection approach to this issue... it's a bit beyond me at this point, though. I ended up leveraging the structuredness of my data and I got by by just flattening my list and making the inner loop track the state. Used a `for file in \`cat file\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash file descriptor 1 is stdin, 2 is stderr, and after 9 can be used by internal shell processes. (from bash man page) (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089 for examples)

```
Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used  with
care,  as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses inter‐
nally.
```

So you can read your files into 3-9 e.g. (replace echo with however you're getting files)

```
for file in $(echo "file1.txt file2.txt"); do
  while IFS='' read differingfilepair <&3; do
    ...
    printf "Continue? (Y/n)"
    read -n1 cont
  done 3< "$file" #Or some command that gets file names
done
```

Comment: Excellent. Could you also note how to use a different file descriptor to pipe something into the `while`?

Comment: Perfect answer. Only critique is that TLDP probably isn't the best reference to point folks at, as it often tends to be outdated or inaccurate. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089 is another reference directly on-point.

Comment: @Steven Lu Do you have to pipe it? Getting a bad file descriptor warning when I tried it a second ago. I'm sure there is some magic way to get it, but may just be easier to sequentially redirect them in.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks, added to post for reference

Comment: re: recent edits: `for file in $(echo ...)` is actually bad practice; see entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, and how it applies to find &c. also.

Comment: Hmm. I guess sequential redirection is how e.g. implementing this (quite straightforwardly I might add) in Python would do it right? How exactly would a scripting language intepreter relinquish stdin to read a file and then get it back?

Comment: ...also, bash 4.2 supports automatic FD allocation, so you can safely get more than 10 FDs by asking the shell to give you a free one: `exec {new_fd}<somefile` will assign the FD number to `new_fd`, such that you can then `read ... <&$new_fd`.

Comment: @StevenLu well, idiomatic use of files in Python isn't using `sys.stdin` at all, but is using a different FD number for its reads. You can do that in bash, too: `read -u "$new_fd"` will use the FD number in `new_fd`, rather than relying on FD 0 to be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this *just might* do the trick:

```
read -n1 cont </dev/tty
```

Possible duplicate of [Read input in bash inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop)