# waiting to enter any key does not work in while loop

Tags: shell, while-loop, scripting

i am using read -p "Press any key to continue" in my script. 
This works fine except when it is in a while loop like

```
while read TEST_NAME  ; do
    read -p "Press any key..."
    echo "Executing:"
done <$MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR/automation.mts
```

i am suspecting it is because of the enclosing while looping doing the read as well. so what would be the solution for it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is indeed the enclosing redirection. You can simply redirect the inner `read` input from `/dev/tty` (your keyboard) that way:

```
while read TEST_NAME  ; do
    read -p "Press any key..." < /dev/tty
    echo "Executing:"
done <$MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR/automation.mts
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `read`s are reading from the same input file. Use a different file descriptor for the first read, letting the second `read` inherit whatever your script is using.

```
while read TEST_NAME <&3  ; do
    read -p "Press any key..."
    echo "Executing:"
done 3< "$MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR"/automation.mts
```