# Wait for keypress in a while loop and stop script

Tags: bash

I'd like to wait for keypress and exit when pressed the letter `q`.
The script isn't waiting for a key. How to correct it?

```
while read line
do
    ...
    while :
    do
        read -n 1 key

        if [[ $key = q ]]
        then
            break
        fi
    done
done < $1
```

Comment: See: [Read input in bash inside a while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6883363/3776858)

Comment: With `break` you only terminate the inner `while` loop. With `break 2` you can terminate 2 loops (but difficult when somebody else changes the code). When you put t in a function you can use `return`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` reads the input.

In your script, the input is changed to `$1`.

The first level `while` loop is reading a line from the file for which the name is stored into `$1`, and `read -n 1 key` reads and stores the first char of the next line from the same file.

Give a try to that :

```
while read line ; do
  while : ; do
    read -n 1 key <&1
    if [[ $key = q ]] ; then
      break
    fi
  done
done < $1
```

`<&1` is the standard input.

Comment: also change `break` to `break 2` or `exit`.

Comment: True, thank you for the hint (I had never used it). I am not sure what the OP would like to achieve...

Comment: Exactly. This helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> The script isn't waiting for a key.

- Because the command `read` is getting its input from the redirected file in:

  ```
  done < $1           ### Should be "$1".
  ```

That file is consumed by both `read` commands (and anything else inside the loop that read stdin).

The correct solution for shell's `read` that have the option `-u` (and bash does), is to define the `fd` (file descriptor) to use in each read while the file is redirected to some `fd` number (greater than 2):

```
while read -u 3 line ; do
    while : ; do
    read -u 1 -n 1 key
    if [[ $key = q ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    done
    echo "$line"
done 3< "$1"
```

That makes the first read get the input from `fd 3` which comes from the file (`done 3< "$1"`), and the second read get the input from `fd 1` (stdin).

For POSIX shells, read does not have the `-u` option, we need to perform some redirections to get the same general effect:

```
#!/bin/dash

while read line <&3; do
    while : ; do
        read key <&1
        if [ "$key" = q ] ; then
            break
        fi
    done
done 3< "$1"
```

Sadly, this also remove the `-n 1` option from read and each key from the keyboard must be followed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To actually read one character we may use `dd`. And we also may set the actual terminal as `/dev/tty` (blocks any other redirection) and if we need to hide the text typed (or passwords) use `stty -echo`:

```
#!/bin/dash
while read line <&3; do
    while : ; do
        stty raw -echo
        key=$(dd bs=1 count=1 </dev/tty 2> /dev/null)
        stty -raw echo
        if [ "$key" = q ] ; then
            break
        fi
    done
    echo "$line"
done 3< "$1"
```

Caveat: setting `stty raw` will prevent the effect of keys like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (be careful).