# "read" command not executing in "while read line" loop

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, line-by-line

First post here! I really need help on this one, I looked the issue on google, but can't manage to find an useful answer for me. So here's the problem.
I'm having fun coding some like of a framework in bash. Everyone can create their own module and add it to the framework. BUT. To know what arguments the script require, I created an "args.conf" file that must be in every module, that kinda looks like this:

```
LHOST;true;The IP the remote payload will connect to.
LPORT;true;The port the remote payload will connect to.
```

The first column is the argument name, the second defines if it's required or not, the third is the description. Anyway, long story short, the framework is supposed to read the args.conf file line by line to ask the user a value for every argument. Here's the piece of code:

```
info "Reading module $name argument list..."
while read line; do
    echo $line > line.tmp
    arg=`cut -d ";" -f 1 line.tmp`
    requ=`cut -d ";" -f 2 line.tmp`
    if [ $requ = "true" ]; then
        echo "[This argument is required]"
    else
        echo "[This argument isn't required, leave a blank space if you don't wan't to use it]"
    fi
    read -p " $arg=" answer
    echo $answer >> arglist.tmp
done < modules/$name/args.conf
tr '\n' ' ' < arglist.tmp > argline.tmp
argline=`cat argline.tmp`
info "Launching module $name..."
cd modules/$name
$interpreter $file $argline
cd ../..
rm arglist.tmp
rm argline.tmp
rm line.tmp
succes "Module $name execution completed."
```

As you can see, it's supposed to ask the user a value for every argument... But:

1) The read command seems to not be executing. It just skips it, and the argument has no value

2) Despite the fact that the args.conf file contains 3 lines, the loops seems to be executing just a single time. All I see on the screen is "[This argument is required]" just one time, and the module justs launch (and crashes because it has not the required arguments...).

Really don't know what to do, here... I hope someone here have an answer ^^'.
Thanks in advance!

(and sorry for eventual mistakes, I'm french)

Alpha.

Comment: Your `while read line` and `read -p " $arg" answer` are competing for the same data. Are you trying to read from the user? The easiest hack is `read -p " $arg=" answer < /dev/tty`

Comment: See [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop) for an example of a good [mcve] -- taking four lines rather than 20 to ask the same question by focusing specifically and directly on the problem at hand, removing all unrelated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @that other guy pointed out in a comment, the problem is that all of the `read` commands in the loop are reading from the args.conf file, not the user. The way I'd handle this is by redirecting the conf file over a different file descriptor than stdin (fd #0); I like to use fd #3 for this:

```
while read -u3 line; do
    ...
done 3< modules/$name/args.conf
```

(Note: if your shell's `read` command doesn't understand the `-u` option, use `read line <&3` instead.)

There are a number of other things in this script I'd recommend against:

- Variable references without double-quotes around them, e.g. `echo $line` instead of `echo "$line"`, and `< modules/$name/args.conf` instead of `< "modules/$name/args.conf"`. Unquoted variable references get split into words (if they contain whitespace) and any wildcards that happen to match filenames will get replaced by a list of matching files. This can cause *really* weird and intermittent bugs. Unfortunately, your use of `$argline` depends on word splitting to separate multiple arguments; if you're using `bash` (not a generic POSIX shell) you can use arrays instead; I'll get to that.
- You're using relative file paths everywhere, and `cd`ing in the script. This tends to be fragile and confusing, since file paths are different at different places in the script, and any relative paths passed in by the user will become invalid the first time the script `cd`s somewhere else. Worse, you aren't checking for errors when you `cd`, so if any `cd` fails for any reason, then entire rest of the script will run in the wrong place and fail bizarrely. You'd be far better off figuring out where your system's root directory is (as an absolute path), then referencing everything from it (e.g. `< "$module_root/modules/$name/args.conf"`).
- Actually, you're not checking for errors anywhere. It's generally a good idea, when writing any sort of program, to try to think of what can go wrong and how your program should respond (and also to expect that things you didn't think of will also go wrong). Some people like to use `set -e` to make their scripts exit if any simple command fails, but [this doesn't always do what you'd expect](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). I prefer to explicitly test the exit status of the commands in my script, with something like:

  ```
  command1 || {
      echo 'command1 failed!' >&2
      exit 1
  }
  if command2; then
      echo 'command2 succeeded!' >&2
  else
      echo 'command2 failed!' >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  ```
- You're creating temp files in the current directory, which risks random conflicts (with other runs of the script at the same time, any files that happen to have names you're using, etc). It's better to create a temp directory at the beginning, then store everything in it (again, by absolute path):

  ```
  module_tmp="$(mktemp -dt module-system)" || {
      echo "Error creating temp directory" >&2
      exit 1
  }
  ...
  echo "$answer" >> "$module_tmp/arglist.tmp"
  ```

  (BTW, note that I'm using `$()` instead of backticks. They're easier to read, and don't have some subtle syntactic oddities that backticks have. I recommend switching.)
- Speaking of which, you're overusing temp files; a lot of what you're doing with can be done just fine with shell variables and built-in shell features. For example, rather than reading line from the config file, then storing them in a temp file and using `cut` to split them into fields, you can simply `echo` to `cut`:

  ```
  arg="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ";" -f 1)"
  ```

  ...or better yet, use `read`'s built-in ability to split fields based on whatever `IFS` is set to:

  ```
  while IFS=";" read -u3 arg requ description; do
  ```

  (Note that since the assignment to `IFS` is a prefix to the `read` command, it only affects that one command; changing `IFS` globally can have weird effects, and should be avoided whenever possible.)

  Similarly, storing the argument list in a file, converting newlines to spaces into another file, then reading that file... you can skip any or all of these steps. If you're using `bash`, store the arg list in an array:

  ```
  arglist=()
  while ...
      arglist+=("$answer") # or ("#arg=$answer")? Not sure of your syntax.
  done ...

  "$module_root/modules/$name/$interpreter" "$file" "${arglist[@]}"
  ```

  (That messy syntax, with the double-quotes, curly braces, square brackets, and at-sign, is the generally correct way to expand an array in `bash`).

  If you can't count on `bash` extensions like arrays, you can at least do it the old messy way with a plain variable:

  ```
  arglist=""
  while ...
      arglist="$arglist $answer" # or "$arglist $arg=$answer"? Not sure of your syntax.
  done ...

  "$module_root/modules/$name/$interpreter" "$file" $arglist
  ```

  ... but this runs the risk of arguments being word-split and/or expanded to lists of files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, my coding is always messy, I'm not really good at organizing things like this ^^'. I'll try to keep in mind your advices ^^. Btw, I know about that arg="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ";" -f 1)" thing, I normally always use it, but I don't know why, when I use it in this piece of code, it says "command cut not found"... I have to use it the way I did, or it doesn't work... Anyway, thank you both for your answers, gonna try it right now!