# gitk and hook script

Tags: git, githooks

I want to deploy a hook script to control format of commit message. For this I use the `prepare-commit-msg` script.

I want to check if the commit message starts with a number of 3 digits. If this is the case, the script returns `0`, otherwise `1`.

It works fine for an utilisation with the `git` command, but it doesn't when used with `gitk`. When script returns `1`, the commit is not aborded. I don't manage to display message either (an information message explaining why commit will be abort).

Is there a way to use hook script with `gitk`?

Thanks.

PS: I use git version 1.8.5.3

Comment: The `prepare-commit-msg` prepares a commit message for new commit. (Thus on calling `git commit`). `gitk` is used only for viewing the git history. No hooks can be executed then.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Git client-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks), the `prepare-commit-msg` hook is run **before the commit message editor is fired up** but after the default message is created.
So that would not feed your requirement. It would be better to use a `commit-msg` hook.

> The `commit-msg` hook takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the commit message written by the developer.
>   If this script exits non-zero, Git aborts the commit process, so you can use it to validate your project state or commit message before allowing a commit to go through.

After that, it depends on how your script is written: see "[How do I prompt the user from within a commit-msg hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3417896/6309)", and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633559/6309) in particular:

> if you use `gitk` or `git-gui` you won't be able to prompt because you get an error on the "`exec < /dev/tty`" line.

You can replace that by a function defined in your hook bash script

```
function f_askContinue {
  local myQuestion=$1

  while true; do
     read -p "${myQuestion} " -n 1 -r answer
     case $answer in
        [Yy]* ) printf "\nOK\n"; break;;
        [Nn]* )   printf "\nAbandon\n";
                  exit;;
        * ) printf "\nAnswer with Yes or No.\n";;
     esac
  done
}

f_askContinue "Do you want to continue ?"
```

(Adapt that to the logic you want to implement in your control)

That would work from gitk.