# Redirect to a script that uses /dev/tty

Tags: bash, stdout, tty

I am writing a git hook that might require human input. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/7069123) one has to use `exec < /dev/tty` in that script. This does the job, but now there is no possibility to redirect the standard output to that hook (for test purposes). I guess the problem can be narrowed down to a question: how to send a message to `/dev/tty` in such a way that another process will read it? Not sure if this is even possible.

Here is the minimum reproducible example:

```sh
# file: target.sh

exec < /dev/tty # we want to use /dev/tty
read -p  "Type a message: " message
echo "The message ${message}"
```

I tried several solutions like this:

```sh
echo -e "foo\n"| tee /dev/tty | source target.sh
```

And it actually prints the message in the console after the `read` prompt, but the `message` variable remains unset. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expect` to achieve the result:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect << EOF
spawn bash target.sh
expect {
    "Type a message: " {send "foo\r"; interact}
}
EOF
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's the solution I was looking for. And it actually plays well with the test cases I was about to write

Answer (score 2):

You could make the input file an optional parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file=${1:-/dev/tty}
read -p  "Type a message: " message < "${input_file}"
echo "The message ${message}"

# other stuff ...
```

Now test the command like this:

```
your_script
your_script <(echo foo)
some_cmd | your_script
some_cmd | your_script <(echo foo)
```

PS: The syntax `<(echo foo)` which I'm using is a so called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I upvoted your approach as I like it, but I can't mark it as accepted. I am planning to use it in the git hook, there will be no option to pass the input file parameter. And I am curious if there any way  to solve this `/dev/tty` issue. Anyways, your solution looks like a good practice for writing the custom scripts, thanks

Comment: The input file parameter defaults to /dev/tty, that's the point. In the git-hook you just don't pass a filename (check the examples). Use expect if you prefer that, but that's imo way more complicated, plus it requires that users have expect installed

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault, I wasn't clear enough. I was assuming end-to-end tests. For example something like `echo -e "some information\n" | git commit -m "message"` (it's not a working example just to show my point). In this case `git` shadows the parameter and I am not sure if it's possible to override. Yes, users might not have `expect` installed, but they are not supposed to. It's enough to have it in CI environment. But you actually gave me another hint :D, I can test the hook separately as a regular script, without any `git` calls.