# ask committer name and email every git commit

Tags: git

if you git commit without telling git who you are you get a message like this

```
$ git commit -m "From Qworp"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

How can I make *every single*  `git commit` prompt for user.name and user.email? something like

```
$ git commit -am "From Qworp"
user.name: Qworp
user.email: qworp@qworp.com
[master be42c9e] From Qworp
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
...
$ git commit -am "Now Ace"
user.name: Ace
user.email: ace@qworp.com
[master 56ec176] Now Ace
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

And set author and committer details based on that?

Comment: That's not supported out of the box. Do you simply want to pretend to be someone else for each commit or is there some underlying problem that you're trying to solve? If it's the first one, I'd write a shell script to wrap `git commit`and make that change the config before each commit. Note that you can use `--author` to specify the author on the command line.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, the first one exactly. Thanks for such a clear comment. I guess I'll take a look at wrapping it

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Different defaults for different repos? I use [conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) for that purpose...

Comment: @kapsiR: that could already be solved by simply configuring those values per-repo, no need to complicate it further.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes but not for every new repo. If I would rely on that with e.g. the global defaults, then it wouldn't work for me - that's the reason why I have folder based defaults.

Comment: do you want the commiter or the author to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a git hook would be the way to go. But even in the first git hook `pre-commit` that runs, the user is already set. Therefore, use the following wrapper around `git`. Define this function inside your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`.

```bash
git() {
  local opts=()
  if [ "$1" = commit ]; then
    read -p "user.name: " name
    read -p "user.email: " email
    opts+=(-c user.name="${name}" -c user.email="${email}")
  fi
  command git "${opts[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: Why did you change to a bash answer instead of git pre-commit ?

Comment: Thank you for the note and please excuse my poor tests. Git hooks do not have stdin by default. You can read stdin using [`exec < /dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/6770384). However, I found that `git config user.name` does not affect the current commit inside `pre-commit`, but only future ones. My bad. Seems like git hooks aren't the right approach here, so I switched to a wrapper function.

Comment: Can a pre-commit not change the author/committer for the current commit?

Comment: I cannot say for sure. But so far I haven't found a way. Maybe a `git commit --amend` in a  `post-commit` hook works, but that would be error prone if the users aborts a commit midway using ctrl+c.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this

Comment: @user3840170 why is it not safe to run git many times in a row/