# Possible to record user input on GIT UI (IntelliJ Git, Sourceforge)? Specifically in the case of git hooks

Tags: git, stdin, githooks, husky

I am working on trying to find if its feasible to collect user input from a git hook when the git commands are being performed in a graphical interface like IntelliJ or SourceForge. I am able to open a "/dev/tty" in the terminal and "CON" for Windows

See threads here and here for this workaround: [How do I prompt the user from within a commit-msg hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417896/how-do-i-prompt-the-user-from-within-a-commit-msg-hook)

and https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli/issues/627.

However, when using a GIT GUI the git operations are hanging since they are trying to collect user input in the background. I can confirm this through IntelliJ looking at the console, but I am not able to directly enter commands into the console.

Any suggestions of workarounds to try to see if its feasible to prompt the user somehow, like possibly opening up a new terminal window to collect user input, from my investigation it doesn't seem possible